# .htaccess redirect issue with language

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to make my .htaccess file redirect to https by default but, I also want to use the language directory.

e.g. I want the following redirects:

1. http://example.org -> https://example.org/en/Home
2. www.example.org -> https://example.org/en/Home
3. example.org/test?test=test -> https://example.org/en/test?test=test

***Note, en should be the browser default language or the cookie 'Language' when set. The cookie should rank above the browser default***

So, What my .htaccess-file looks like at the moment is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.org
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/example\.org\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?$ "/Home" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/?$ /$1/Home [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.+)?/?$ $2/?Language=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /404/
ErrorDocument 500 /500/
```

Comment: Are you setting the lang cookie using php or mod-rewrite?

Comment: No, on first page load the default will be browser default language. However, on later visite the cookie is set. If you have any other alternative, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try with below conditions, I didn't tried for now.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [OR]
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+?)$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.org/en%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however when Cookie Language is set I want /en/ to be replaced with the cookie value e.g. de or es or similar. When cookie is not set, en should be the browser default code